# Android data synchronize with database every day same time

Tags: android, synchronization

I want my app to synchronize data with server every 24 hours. What way should i choose ? 
Should i make a service or something ? cant find the right way to start doing this

Comment: which option would be better ? pluses and minuses ?

Answer (score 1):

U have to mention this inside the String.xml .You have to call with default SyncDateTime.

```
   <integer name="default_sync_time">900000</integer>

    <string name="defaultSyncEvery">900000</string>
```

Comment: in case of using asynctask ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use AlarmManager

It is not only "for alarm"

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html